# Converging sequence of base change

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, local-fields, rigid-analytic-geometry

Here is a natural question that I hope will be of interest to some.

Let $\mathbf{F}_p(\!(T)\!)$ be the field of formal Laurent series over $\mathbf{F}_p$. An automorphism of $\mathbf{F}_p(\!(T)\!)$ is entirely determined by the image of $T$. Let $\lbrace \alpha_n\rbrace_{n\in \mathbf{N}}$ be a sequence of automorphisms of $\mathbf{F}_p(\!(T)\!)$ defined by $\alpha_n(T) = T+T^n$.

$\textbf{Preliminary question}$: Let $X$ be a scheme over $\mathbf{F}_p(\!(T)\!)$. Does there exist a subsequence $\lbrace \alpha_{n_k}\rbrace_{k\in \mathbf{N}}$ such that for all $k\in \mathbf{N}$, $(\alpha_{n_k})_{\ast}X$ is not isomorphic to $X$ over $\mathbf{F}_p(\!(T)\!)$ ? (here, $(\alpha_{n_k})_{\ast}X$ denotes the base change of $X$ along $\alpha_{n_k}$).

If this preliminary question settles in the negative, we can go on and try to prove the more general

$\textbf{Real question:}$ Let $\lbrace \alpha_n\rbrace_{n\in \mathbf{N}}$ be a sequence of automorphisms of $\mathbf{F}_p(\!(T)\!)$ converging to an automorphism $\alpha$. Assume that for all $n$, $(\alpha_n)_{\ast}X$ is $\mathbf{F}_p(\!(T)\!)$-isomorphic to $X$. Does that imply that $\alpha_{\ast}X$ is $\mathbf{F}_p(\!(T)\!)$-isomorphic to $X$ ?

In case it matters, the case of interest is for $X$ a smooth affine scheme of finite type over $\mathbf{F}_p(\!(T)\!)$, and even an algebraic group

P.S.: I've put the tag rigid-analytic-geometry hoping that it might actually be relevant, but I actually have no idea if that's the case. Feel free to change tags has appropriate. I've also added the tag algebraic groups since the motivation of the question comes from trying to understand the abstract automorphism group of an algebraic group.